# trouble converting xml to somehting usable in php

Tags: php, xml, simplexml, soap-client

I am getting a xml response from doing:

```
$foo = $client->__doRequest (parameters here)
```

when I echo out $foo I get the xml exactly as I'm told I should. The problem is now I want to extract some values from the xml. Now the easiest way I can see to do that is to convert it to a php array and then is super simple to get value and do lots of lovely stuff with but I seem to be having trouble doing this. Have seen a lot of examples using simple_load_xml but all I get is 'Notice: Array to string conversion in'. When I var_dump '$foo' I get 'string 'xml' '.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you need to parse XML in PHP, just use DOMDocument : http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

Comment: please be more specific on what exactly you want to accomplish, how your XML looks like, how your code looks like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @CD001 I persevered with DOMDocument and figured it out in the end with the following code:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML($xml);
$things = $dom->getElementsByTagName('chocolate');

/** I only had a single result so had to do it this way rather then a loop**/

if($things->length > 0) {
  $node = $things->item(0);
  $chocolate = $node->nodeValue;
} 
else {
  // empty result set
}
echo $chocolate;
```

bah! JSON is so much nicer...

Comment: This is only true until you understand Xpath and Namespaces. After that JSON is a lot more work. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use Xpath:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

// get content of the first chocolate element node as a string
$chocolate = $xpath->evaluate('string(//chocolate)');

echo $chocolate;
```